# How can I make Photoshop extensions in CS3 up to CC versions

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

Researching the subject I realized that HTML5 and javascript is perfectly good to go stack for building an extensions for versions of Photoshop beginning from CC up to the latest CC 2015 versions. I want to build an extension that is compatible with versions begining from CS3 to CC 2015. And the question is: can I do that just using HTML5 and javascript? (for example Brackets plugin for building extensions) or should I use some other technologies to do that? And is it possible in general to make a fully compatible extension for all the Photoshop versions from CS3 to CC 2015? Would be really greatful for any tips and answers!

Comment: You can write scripts using JavaScript and the Extend Script Toolkit makes it easier and it will work in CS3 (as long as the APIs/functionalities you use are also supported by CS3). I have't used other tools for extensions, but I imagine they'll be more like tools and wrappers to package the scripts as a nice easy to install extension. When packaging an extension, there should be compatibility options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you use Configurator? I found this option for building extensions for CC and below versions. How does it plays nicely with HTML panels which are build with Extension builder? Or should it be two different versions of extensions (which will be supported by all versions started CS3 to CC 2015), one builded with Configurator using flash and the other using HTML?

Comment: Having a quick look at the [Configurator page](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/configurator/) it appears to support CC and CS6, but no mention of CS3, so my guess is it probably won't support CS3. I would ask on the Adobe Forums as well, perhaps the [Extension Manager forums](https://forums.adobe.com/community/creativesuites/extensionmanager). In terms of putting together a basic UI, in Extension Manager open **Help > Object Model Viewer** and checkout the Script UI classes. That's what I usually go for. You won't have the fancy IDE support of something like Extension Builder, but it works.